# Convert Unicode Strings to Python List

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, unicode

I have this

```
x = "BA ( Socialogy)", "DAE ( Civil)", "MA ( Internation Relation", "BS'c"
print x
<type 'unicode'>
```

I wanted to convert it into python list like this

```
['BA (Socialogy)', 'DAE (Civil)','MA (Internation Relation)', 'BSc']
```

Note that last index of **x** has "BS'c" , quotes in between how to handle this thing.

**UPDATE:**

What actually I am trying to do is to get all user's degrees titles from database and combine in one list.

```
SELECT 
string_agg(distinct(E'\"'||title||E'\"'), ', ') as degree_titles, 
FROM education
WHERE user_id = 5
GROUP BY r.resume_id;
```

on python Script.

```
    try:
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute(sql_query)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    else:
        rows = c.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print row[2]
            print type(row[2])
```

it outputs

```
"BA ( Socialogy)", "DAE ( Civil)", "MA ( Internation Relation", "BS'c"
<type 'unicode'>
```

More if I update my query to this then i get this.

```
   SELECT 
    string_agg(distinct(E'\''||title||E'\''), ', ') as degree_titles, 
    FROM education
    WHERE user_id = 5
    GROUP BY r.resume_id;
```

Then i will get this

```
'BA ( Socialogy)', 'DAE ( Civil)', 'MA ( Internation Relation', 'BS'c'
```

Then i use this code to convert it into list

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval('[' + str(row[2]) + ']')
```

and it gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax on last value of `'BS'c'`

Comment: I am not getting `<type 'unicode'>` please check this `>>> x = "BA ( Socialogy)", "DAE ( Civil)", "MA ( Internation Relation", "BS'c"
>>> print x
('BA ( Socialogy)', 'DAE ( Civil)', 'MA ( Internation Relation', "BS'c")
`

Comment: You might be missing some code part, please give full example.

Comment: this string is Coming from postures database. that is why it print Unicode to me.

Comment: You want code that magically cleans up your spaces and punctuation too? Could you be more specific about what you are requesting?

Comment: @MTaqi, please give code which u have, your peace of code cant produce what u are asking :(

Comment: @Lafada Check the updated question

Comment: The solution is to not concatenate your strings in the database; its not adding any value and it is just making your life difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Please split your data return from db

```
...
...
for row in rows:
        split_data = [x.strip()[1:-2] for x in row[2].split(",")]
        print split_data
        print type(split_data)
```

Comment: well now it becomes this `[u"'BA ( Socialogy)'", u" 'DAE ( Civil)'", u" 'MA ( Internation Relation'", u"BS'c"]`